# Hibernate identity primary key generator and foreign keys

Tags: java, hibernate, primary-key, identity

Looked in many places and found that the hibernate with postgresql can use an IDENTITY primary key generator which maps into serial/bigserial table column. Suppose i have follow entity:

```
@Entity
class A {

    long id;

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public long getId() { return id; }

}
```

Works good and ddl looks like:

```
create table A (id bigserial)
```

Unfortunatelly any attempt to reference to 'a' via @ManyToOne produces the foreign key column which is also bigserial.

```
@Entity
class B {

    // id ommitted ...

    A a;

    @ManyToOne
    public A getA() {
      return a;
    }

}
```

generates ddl like follow:

```
create table B (..., a_id bigserial)
```

In most cases this will work ok. But the logically it is completly wrong. a_id has nothing to do with bigserial "datatype" either.

It there any way to tell hibernate to use bigint for column a_id in the table B ?

Tried to override with columnDefinition in the @JoinColumn or @Column annotations for a getter with no luck. Hibernate completly ignores these annotation attributes.

Comment: Foreign keys pretty much have to have the same number of columns as the primary key they reference, with the same type. What exactly is the problem you think is being created here?

Comment: If I understand the OP correctly, the foreign key is being created with a datatype of bigserial, which is a sequence that generates values of type `bigint`. Logically, when the referenced column (A.id) is of type `bigserial`, the foreign key referencing it (B.a_id) *should* be of type `bigint`.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The foreign column should be of type bigint, not the bigserial. Default value generated by postgres via bigserial "datatype" can cause a problems and as i said before - logically wrong.

Comment: What is the hibernate 's version ? I try with hibernate 3.6.10 and does not have this problem . It generate :`create table A (id  bigserial not null, primary key (id))` and
`create table B (id  bigserial not null, a_id int8, primary key (id))`

Comment: Finally found a cause. It was trivial - wrong classpath. Compiled classes were used from some of the experiment point with wrong columnDefinition at the primary key. Closed.

Comment: Anyway thanks for all who spent time answering my question. alot.